# Did .loc at some point work with only ints in pandas?

Tags: pandas

I have a short question.
There is this snippet of code that I found on a github repo for a project that is similar to what I am working on:

```
for i in range(1, len(pred_class) - 1):
    if pred_prob.loc[i, int(pred_class[i - 1])] > pred_prob.loc[i, int(pred_class[i + 1])]:
```

The way `loc` is used here surprises me. It basically is `pred_prob.loc[loop index,int]`. This gives me an error message. Did this work at all at some point? I didn't see anything in the pandas documentation. It states:

> Access a group of rows and columns by label(s) or a boolean array

This is clearly not the case for this code. Am I missing something or did someone mess up the code and actually never tested it?

Comment: No. `.loc` has always been `.loc[row_labels, col_labels]`. In the repo's case, both labels are `ints`. Yours may not be.

Comment: Yes, but doesn't that mean that the repo code can never work because it never calls labels but ints?

Comment: I think you are confusing `loc` (index value based access) and `iloc` (position based lookup).

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by Code Different: This actually works if the column label is of type int. My mistake was that the index labels said "0" and "1" but I didn't realise that they are actually string.